# Unity4.6 uGUIのボタンサイズなどのスマホ対応について

Tags: unity3d, ugui

Unity4.6で追加されたuGUIでボタンやGUIを追加したときに
Android SDKで使用されているViewを均等配列するandroid:layout_weight="1"と同等の仕様はありますか？

実装したいUIとしてはiOSの電卓のように正方形、または正方形複数分のボタンを均等に配置したいと考えています

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uGUIの機能でGameObjectを等間隔に並べるには `Horizontal Layout Group` や `Vertical Layout Group` , `Grid Layout Group` を使います。

Auto Layout
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/comp-UIAutoLayout.html

スマホ対応については `Canvas Scaler` を使うのですが、
詳しくはテラシュールブログさんの記事が参考になると思います。
http://tsubakit1.hateblo.jp/entry/2014/12/11/223427